# Cuando creo un proyecto de Ionic, se crea uno de angular

Tags: ionic

el caso es que normalmente he estado trabajando con proyectos de ionic y los creaba tan simple como "ionic start project blank" pero hace poco empecé a trabajar también con proyectos de angular y bootstrap que creaba con "ng new project", el caso es que ahora, por algún motivo que desconozco, cuando intento crear un proyecto de ionic se crea otra cosa que no es ionic, no llega a ser igual que un proyecto de angular pero no es ionic. Adjunto imágenes de la instalación, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay nada incorrecto en lo que estás haciendo. Simplemente estás creando un proyecto de Ionic 4. Seguramente actualizaste el cli y como venías usando la versión 3 te pareció raro.

Te dejo un ejemplo de la estructura de un proyecto de Ionic 4.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes razón, he hecho un downgrade hacia cli 3 y ha vuelto a la normalidad, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Por nada! :) Si te ha servido, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta.